# Errors when GETing and POSTing an image in Meteor

Tags: http, post, meteor, amazon-s3, get

I have a webapp that's collecting photos, and uploading them to AWS S3. Periodically, I go through and review the photos, and appropriate ones are then uploaded to another webservice. That's where I'm having problems. I use use `HTTP.get` to retrieve the image content from S3, then have attempted to use `HTTP.post` to send the content to the other webservice, which gives me an error 'Invalid Object Type.' I know the other webservice works, as I'm able to upload directly to it by POSTing a form with a file directly.

```
function uploadImageTest(){
var thisImage = HTTP.get("https://381-crowd.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/y2svBWnk95ACo3h9s/1427384292798-backgroundImage.jpg", {}, function(error, result){
  var postURL = "https://www.onuma.com/plan/webservices/post.php";
  var options = {
    content: result.content,
    query: {
      u: "username",
      p: "password",
      sysID: "sysID",
      bldgID: "bldgID",
      rawname: "fromMeteor",
      ext: ".jpg",
      attach: ""
    },        
  };
  HTTP.post(postURL, options, function(error2, result2){
    console.log("Posted File: " + error2 + " _ " + result2.content);
  });
});
}
```

Any idea as to why simply posting the content of the image wouldn't be accepted as a valid image, like it would if sent by a form?

**edit:** This bit of code works for uploading a file. I do know that it needs to have the `name` attribute in the input to work:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://www.onuma.com/plan/webservices/post.php?u=username&p=password&sysID=sysID&bldgID=bldgID&rawname=essential&ext=.jpg&attach">
<input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

**Edit 2:** Here's a working curl command...took a while to get it running :/

```
"https://www.onuma.com/plan/webservices/post.php?u=<username>&p=<password>&sysID=<sysID>&bldgID=<bldgID>&rawname=redX&ext=.jpg&attach="
```

Comment: what is `result.content`? It is a multi-part message, or is it just the binary data of the image? if the latter, then that's most probably wrong. Can you show a curl call that works for the php script you are posting to, so we can understand what format the server expects?

Comment: I'm a bit new to using curl, and I'm finding it a bit tricky to get it working. I do have this snippet that works, and I've added it to the original post.

Comment: you need to create content in the multipart/form-data format, not just send your binary data in the content. There should a ton of example of how to do that in javascript (it's not meteor specific).